# How to solve an OutOfMemory exception when I load a big number of JSON files in Spark using and HDFS source

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

## The problem:

I have a hdfs source `hdfs:///data` that contains 500 GB of JSON files.

My executor node memory limit is 64 GB, my Spark version is 3.3.0, and I am running on AWS EMR 6.8.

```scala
val df = spark.read.option("recursiveFileLookup","true").json("hdfs:///data")
```

## The issue

I got an exception when I use this spark command. How do I solve this issue ?

I have just used this command and never executed a side effect such as "save", but I got the memory exception.

```bash
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 4314"...
```

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 9571 tasks (1024.0 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2863)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2799)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2798)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2798)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1239)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1239)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1239)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3051)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoo
```

Comment: Hi Raphael! Spark is easily able to read files larger than memory. To answer your question, more info is needed. Executing `spark.read.json()` will only be actually executed if there is some kind of action done on your `df`. Could you add the rest of your code to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Also, I assume that with 500 GO you are using the French notation. Since this website is English spoken, could you edit your post and turn 500 GO / 64 GO into 500 GB / 64 GB?

Comment: I have just used this command and never executed a side effect such as "save", but I got the memory exception.

Comment: Can you add the error stack trace to your question? There will be interesting info in there.

Comment: I have tried spark-shell --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=32g --conf spark.driver.memory=64g --conf spark.executor.memory=64g

Comment: How many files live inside of the `hdfs:///data` directory?